# android-studio project git private folder

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I have an android project I'm working on using android studio and a git repository. I want to start working on separate files (graphic files) that will not originally be part of the app. Later I will edit them and include them in the app (things like icons and background images). I want to include them in the git repository somewhere. What is the best place. I was thinking of putting them in a folder at the very root of the git repository and giving it a descriptive name. Is there a common way to do this?

```
git/
    personal/
    app/
    build/
    gen/
    gradle/
    other-files
```

Is 'personal' what I want? Maybe I want 'assets' or 'personal-assets'. What do people commonly do?

Answer (score 0):

I would nest them in assets under another folder. I don't know what domain you are working in but I think something as descriptive as possible would be best. I would just make sure you ignore that directory in git if you do not want to push those files to your repo. Git hub has a link on how to do this.  https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I want to keep these files under version control. What do I call a personal folder? Is it ok to have a personal folder under my root git folder?